# Can't connect to Internet through iPhone 4s hotspot on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, iphone, hotspot

I connected my iPhone 4s to my Windows 8.1 PC over usb. I connected to iPhone wifi hotspot on windows but the connection is limited and can't connect to Internet on windows. I can connect to Internet and browse on my iPhone. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resetting network settings solved the issue.